# How do to center a div over a div

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve. I tried using absolute position and it seemed to work on one screen size but doesn't work for others.

```css
.countdown {
  width: 200px;
  background: #b02d1b;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.countdown-bg {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown"> Final Hours </div>
<div class="countdown-bg"></div>
```

Comment: post html and css code

Comment: use text-align:center for centering horizontally, and position relative top to positioning over the line.

Comment: you need to post you code

Comment: We need to see your code, there are multiple ways of accomplishing this

Comment: As others have mentioned, we can't troubleshoot your exact situation without seeing your code. You could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you try `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573324/dynamically-center-div-over-another-div)  answer for example.

Comment: Voting to close as you seem to not have tried anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a solution for your question:

```css
.divOuter {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}

.divInner {
  background-color: #cc0000;
  width: 130px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="divOuter">
  <div class="divInner">FINAL HOURS!</div>
</div>
```

Brief explanation:

We have two divs, the second one in the html is on top of the first one. This placement in CSS is called a ***float***.

When we need this effect we use the "position" property of the CSS with values like *Absotule* and *Relative*.

In this case, the first Div makes the thin line and the second Div makes the red rectangle.

The "top", "left", "right" and "button" property of the css causes to align the second Div relative to the first. And the property "margin: auto" causes the internal div to be aligned to the center of the external div.

I hope I've helped!

Comment: Thanks, Denis. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

#### Without flexbox

Wrapp one div inside another div. Make the outer div `position: relative` and the inner div `position: absolute`. Center the inner div with `left` and `transform`

```css
.countdown {
  position: relative;
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.countdown>.content {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #b02d1b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
  <div class="content">Final Hours!</div>
</div>
```

#### With flexbox

The advantage of using flexbox is that you don't have to set positions and that you can center with `justify-content`.

```css
.countdown {
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 15px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.countdown>.content {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #b02d1b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
  <div class="content">Final Hours!</div>
</div>
```